# certificate for this server is invalid (server with self signed SSL certificate)

Tags: ios, server, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to connect my IOS app with my python backend. The data I'm trying to fetch is on a server with a self signed SSL certificate. But every time I try to fetch the data, I get this error: `NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “serverName.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.}) DataTask error: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “serverName.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.`

Does anyone know what might be causing this error? Or how to resolve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS 9 ATS blocking HTTPS request to server with Self-Signed Certficate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207139/ios-9-ats-blocking-https-request-to-server-with-self-signed-certficate)

Comment: "ATS requires that the server’s certificate be trusted by the system. The only way to avoid that is to use an ATS exception to disable ATS for the domain in question. Whether that’s the right thing to do depends on the circumstances.  Why are you using a self-signed certificate?" - source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49954

Comment: I added the certificate to the Keychain (under login), but I'm still having the same problem. It says this certificate is trusted for this account. Does this mean it's also trusted by the system?

Comment: no, it would need to be added to the system keychain, or add an exception for your domain.

Comment: I trusted the certificate on my Mac (system and login keychain), as well as on the IOS simulator I'm using to run the app. But the error is still there. The status in the system (and login) keychain is "certificate trusted for this account". This is really weird. I don't know what is causing this error to be thrown!